# Shorthand for creating a Python dictionary with key as variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x

In javascript, you can create an object in this way:

```js
const a = 5;
const b = 10;

const c = {a, b};
// This will make c = {a: 5, b: 10}
```

Is there a "shorthand" like this in Python?

So far, I have to do:

```py
a = 5
b = 10

c = {'a': a, 'b': b}
```

Comment: That seems brittle. If you change the variable name, the keys will change, which can cause widespread problems depending on what the map is used for.

Comment: There is no analogous shorthand in Python. You can do `dict(locals())` to get a dictionary of all local variables, but that generally isn't useful for anything other than debugging purposes.

Comment: @kaya3 you _can_ use a dictionary comprehension to filter out the dunder locals, though.

Comment: A little more context about the problem you are trying to solve may help reveal some useful features, but this as it stands now is not possible without dirty hacks.

Comment: `c = dict(a=5,b=10)` would avoid needing to define `a` and `b` independently.

Comment: @osuka_ You can, but generally you will have more local variables than just the ones you want to put in the dictionary.

Comment: @kaya3 right - though I can't really think of any good reasons for you to do this, anyway. Smells funny to me

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this specific case is "no", because a and b in your examples are labels for int objects within __main__ or another module. a doesn't have anything resembling an attribute "a".

However, something closer to what you might want is possible, although it certainly is bordering on a dirty hack, depending on exactly what you are doing. For example, if running from main:

```
a = 5
b = 10
c = {i : eval(i) for i in dir() if "_" not in i}
```

This works because "a" and "b" (the names/labels, that is) *do* exist within a higher object, namely __main__ or your module. You need the filter to exclude other hidden attributes. This example is extremely hacky for many reasons, starting with the use of dir(), but the principle would work in more appropriate cases such as when a and b are attributes of a lower object. However, in those cases, I can't imagine why you'd want to do this, as you'd essentially already have exactly that dictionary.

So really the reason that this is quite difficult in python is because there just isn't any need to do it.

Comment: `if '_' not in i` will _nearly certainly_ break - since Python variables almost universally use underscore case.

Comment: *“ain’t any need”* — Well, other languages offer this, like the above mentioned Javascript, or PHP’s `compact('a', 'b')`. The need is exactly the same as in Python: if you happen to want to create a dict, and the key names happen to be the same as variables in your scope, which isn’t an unreasonable situation in reasonably decent code.